# Wrap each item in array with HTML tag

Tags: underscore.js

I have a JavaScript object, part of which has an array of messages in it. I would like to take each item and wrap in `<li>` tags and then collectively in a `<ul>`.

This is a simplified version of the object.

```
var data = {  
      "messages": [
            {"message": "Message one"},
            {"message": "Message two"}
        ]
     }
```

If it helps, I would like to use underscore.js as it's already being used heavily in this project, but it's not essential if a vanilla JS solution is simpler.

I've managed to output list items using [_.map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) but it's adding a comma in between each

```
_.map(data.messages, function(item){
    return '<li>' + item.message + '</li>';
});
```

but it's adding a comma in between each item

```
<ul>
    <li>Message one</li>,
    <li>Message two</li>
</ul>
```

as seen here https://jsfiddle.net/hmbejuvm/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on line 15 of your fiddle

```
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + messages.join('');
```

that's because map returns an array instead of a string, you need to join it with a blank space.

Comment: Great stuff! Do you know if there is a way to take care of the `.join` part inside Underscore? Use something other than `_.map()` perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `reduce` instead